# Comparison operator "==" used in unix isn't running the desired condition when successful

Tags: unix

In my unix script, I'm using a comparison operator "==" to check if the particular count is zero or not. When it satisfies the condition, it should perform further operations. However though the count is matching, it's not running further lines in the loop.

Example:

```
count=`grep "$name-" names.txt | wc -l`
if [ "$count" == 0 ]
then
#do further operations
...
...
else 
echo "Condition is not satisfied"
fi
```

However even though the count is zero, it doesn't seem to accept it and executes only the else loop.
Could you please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-eq` for numerical comparison

```
count=`grep "$name-" names.txt | wc -l`
if [ "$count" -eq 0 ]
then
   ...
fi
```

`=` and `==` compare strings (and your string contains spaces).